# Can I use the Sites folder for whatever I want?

Tags: sharing, webserver

Not realizing that OS X creates a `~/Sites` folder when you enable web sharing, I started putting my sites for MAMP within a `~/Sites` directory, which did not exist on my new laptop. Is this ok, as long as I don't enable web sharing? Even if I did enable it, would something happen to the other files I put in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine, just realize the built in apache server will share the files you have placed there unless you change the apple supplied httpd.conf should you start up web sharing.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to make sure it wouldn't take over and delete any of my files.

Answer (score 1):

Any files you put in the `~/Sites` folder will be treated the same way most web hosts treat the files. HTML, images & scripts (scripts may need special changes to htaccess & httpd.conf) will be served normally from http://my-Mac-name-here.local/~jjeaton/ .

So, like a typical webserver, whatever files you put in there **will not** be changed unless you youself edit/move/delete them.

You should also double check the permissions so that only you have read/write/execute permission and group & others only have read/execute.